# Pass a reference to a Redis instance to a Gorilla/Mux Handler

Tags: go, redis, gorilla

I'm trying to get my hands dirty while playing with some [Gorilla/Mux](https://github.com/gorilla/mux) and [Go-Redis](https://github.com/go-redis/redis) but I'm facing a little implementation problem here.

Essentially I have a project structured like the following:

[image]

Where **redismanager.go** handles the initialization of a Redis Client:

```
package redismanager

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
)

func InitRedisClient() redis.Client {
    client := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
        Addr    : "localhost:6379",
        Password: "",
        DB      : 0, //default
    })

    pong, err := client.Ping().Result()
    if( err != nil ){
        fmt.Println("Cannot Initialize Redis Client ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Redis Client Successfully Initialized . . .", pong)

    return *client
}
```

Where **main.go** calls `redismanager.InitRedisClient` and initializes `mux.Handlers`:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "../redismanager"
    "../api"
)

type RedisInstance struct {
     RInstance *redis.Client
}

func main() {

    //Initialize Redis Client
    client := redismanager.InitRedisClient()
    //Get current redis instance to get passed to different Gorilla-Mux Handlers
    redisHandler := &RedisInstance{RInstance:&client}

    //Initialize Router Handlers
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/todo", redisHandler.AddTodoHandler).
                                       Methods("POST")

    fmt.Println("Listening on port :8000 . . .")

    // Bind to a port and pass our router in
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))

}
```

Now, I can easily define and let work properly `AddTodoHandler` in the same file like:

```
func (c *RedisInstance) AddTodoHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  . . . doSomething
}
```

But, to make things a bit more modular, I'm trying to move all of these `RouteHandlers` inside their respective files in `api` package. In order to make that, I need to pass a reference to `redisHandler` but I'm having some difficulties when trying to make that with an Handler inside `api` package.

For instance, If in the main I add:

```
r.HandleFunc("/todo/{id}", api.GetTodoHandler(&client)).
                                        Methods("GET")
```

with **gettodo.go**

```
package api

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
)

func GetTodoHandler(c *RedisInstance) func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        . . . doSomething
    }
}
```

It works nicely.

I'm still pretty new to Go and haven't found any cleaner solution to that even after several researches and reads.

**Is my approach correct or are there any better ones?**

Comment: I would recommend using an App struct which initializes DB and Routes. And all Redis methods will be called inside.
e.g. `type App struct{Routes *mux.Router, DB     *sql.DB}`

And which will have `App.initializeRoutes` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a function that converts a function with the Redis instance argument to an HTTP handler:

```
func redisHandler(c *RedisInstance,
    f func(c *RedisInstance, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { f(c, w, r) })
}
```

Write your API handlers like this:

```
func AddTodoHandler(c *RedisInstance, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ...
}
```

Add to the mux like this:

```
r.Handler("/todo", redisHandler(client, api.AddTodoHandler)).Methods("POST")
```

where `client` is the Redis instance.

Comment: That's quite clean. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using an App struct which initializes DB and Routes. And all Redis methods will be called inside.
e.g. `type App struct{Routes *mux.Router, DB     *DB_TYPE}`

And which will have `App.initializeRoutes` method.

```
type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB     *redis.NewClient
}

func (a *App) Run(addr string) {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", a.Router))
}


func (a *App) Initialize(addr, password string, db int) error {
    // Connect postgres

    db, err := redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
      Addr:     addr,
      Password: password,
      DB:       db,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Ping to connection
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Set db in Model
    a.DB = db
    a.Router = mux.NewRouter()
    a.initializeRoutes()
    return nil
}


func (a *App) initializeRoutes() {
    a.Router.HandleFunc("/todo", a.AddTodoHandler).Methods("POST")
    a.Router.HandleFunc("/todo/{id}", a.GetTodoHandler).Methods("GET")
}

// AddTodoHandler has access to DB, in your case Redis
// you can replace the steps for Redis.
func (a *App) AddTodoHandler() {
   //has access to DB
   a.DB
}
```

Hope you get the point, you can even extract out the Model work into a separate Struct and then pass it inside **func**'s

Comment: this creates redis connection every time even when you don't need it for a particular route

Answer (score 1):

```
r.HandleFunc("/todo/{id}", redisHandler.api.GetTodoHandler).Methods("GET")
```

Your `redisHandler`, as defined in `main`, has no `api` field, so this naturally doesn't compile.

If you re-defined your `RedisInstance` type in the `api` package, and you defined the handler methods on that type in the method-specific files, then you can initialize your `redisHandler` using that `api.RedisInstance` type and you can delete the `main.RedisInstance` type definition:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/go-redis/redis"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "../redismanager"
    "../api"
)

func main() {

    //Initialize Redis Client
    client := redismanager.InitRedisClient()
    //Get current redis instance to get passed to different Gorilla-Mux Handlers
    redisHandler := &api.RedisInstance{RInstance:&client}

    //Initialize Router Handlers
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/todo", redisHandler.AddTodoHandler).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/todo/{id}", redisHandler.GetTodoHandler).Methods("GET")

    fmt.Println("Listening on port :8000 . . .")

    // Bind to a port and pass our router in
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))

}
```