# Golang/gin: How to Pass db to router functions

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gin

I'm using **gin framework**. And I'm opening the sqlite database in the main function like this

```
func main() {
...
db, err := sql.Open("sqlite3", "./libreread.db")
CheckError(err)
defer db.Close()
...
}
```

And I have these router handlers in the main function.

```
...
r.GET("/", GetHomePage)
r.GET("/signin", GetSignIn)
r.POST("/signin", PostSignIn)
...
```

How to pass that db value through the router handler func `PostSignin(c *gin.Context)` ?

So that I could avoid opening and closing the database each time in the functions.

**UPDATE: I'm using go-sqlite3 package.**

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have your sql client initialized in `db`, then, you can pass it to different routes with

```
r.GET("/", GetHomePageHandler(&db))
```

And in your GetHomePageHandler:

```
func GetHomePageHandler(sqldb *SQLiteConn) func (*gin.Context) {
    return  func (*gin.Context) {
      . . .
    }
}
```

Where `*SQLiteConn` is the type of your sql db instance. I don't know which package you are currently using so this is just an example.

You can find also a more elegant way of solving it [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43696494/4684539),

Comment: I've updated the question. I'm using go-sqlite3. When I pass &db, it tells (undefined: GetHomePage, undefined: *SQLITE.DB). I'm not sure which instance should I mention. Could you update your answer based on this? Thanks!

Comment: I've never used it. Check the type of `db` with `fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(db))` after importing `"reflect"` and then change  `*SQLite.DB` to the proper returned type. Giving a fast view to the library it might be `sqldb  *SQLiteConn` or `sqldb  *SQLiteContext`.